# How can I trim a string which has multiple lines in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string with multiple lines which has a single line break between each lines.
For that I first trim the extra line breaks and then split the string.
The code used is -

```
function trimString(a){
    var i = a.length;
    var x;
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        x = a[j].replace(/^\s*\n/gm,"");
        a[j] = x;
    }
}

function splitLogs(a,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5){
    var i = a.length;
    var x =[];
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        x = a[j].split("\n");
        s1.push(x[0]);
        s2.push(x[1]);
        s3.push(x[2]);
        s4.push(x[3]);
        s5.push(x[4]);
        
    }
}
```

And the above code works fine .

But the issue is when I have a null/blank value in the multi-line string. Whenever a null value is present in a line the string is separated by two line breaks

String1 sample:

```
line1:Processor
    
line2:  
line3:xyz
    
line4:10
    
line5:user
    
line6:zzz
```

String2 sample:

```
line1:xy
    
line2:xz
    
line3:qw
    
line4:10
    
line5:df

line6:gg
```

For the above case If I use the trimString() function the new string obtained is -

```
line1:Processor
line3:xyz
line4:10 
line5:user
line6:zzz
```

which does not serve my purpose of retaining the null value for line2 and results in mixing up line3 values to line2 array values.

Is there any way in which I can split the string and push it to respective variables which I have to dump to a database.

Answer (score 5):

1 - split into separated lines

2 - trim strings

3 - remove empty lines

4 - join it with `\n` separator.

```
const resultString = targetString
  .split('\n')
  .map(line => line.trim())
  .filter(line => Boolean(line))
  .join('\n')
```

Your function would look like this:

```
function trimString(a){
  return a.split('\n')
          .map(line => line.trim())
          .filter(line => Boolean(line))
          .join('\n')
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the tool I use support only till ECMAScript3 ,

Comment: Then you can easily find polyfills for all methods not supported in your env. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill